# Can I access a (private) google spreadsheet by inserting a password in the URL?

Tags: google-sheets

I see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517518/google-spreadsheet-and-http-request-headers) is no, but wondered if there is any update to that.

Thanks.

Comment: Surely this wouldn't be particularly secure...

Comment: Maybe you can use OAuth? http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. You can access it with a "super secret" URL but it is not with the password in the URL. Go into the spreadsheet, click on the "Share" button, and select the "Get link to share" option. Here you can get your "super secret" URL.

Comment: I know of nothing else, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the question you've linked to is very different from what you're trying to do.  Google does have a [Spreadsheets API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/) and it does allow you to access a private spreadsheet.  You have to request access (preferably via OAuth; don't use ClientLogin) if you want to do anything to a private spreadsheet though.  Also, if you don't know what spreadsheet you need ahead of time, you probably have to use the [Documents List API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/overview.html).